# Querying based off of OpportunityHistories

Tags: soql

I am trying to query opportunities that have changed stages in a given time range.  I have been trying to do it by using a subquery on the opportunityHistories and filtering based off of that, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.  I would like to use a query like:

```
Select id, name, quote_created__c, stagename 
from opportunity 
where (select stageName, 
              createddate, 
              systemmodstamp 
         from OpportunityHistories 
        where createddate > 2018-02-27T00:00:00.000Z 
        and createddate < 2018-02-27T19:05:00.000Z) != null
```

Whenever I run this it says

> Unknown error parsing query.

Is there any way to check if a subquery returns results in a where clause?  Or is there a better way of searching for opportunities that have changed stage in a time range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You simply need to bind the OpportunityId in the field list, and you'll get the opportunities that match the sub-query; this is called a semi-join. You can read more in the [SOQL reference guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin).

```
Select id, name, quote_created__c, stagename 
from opportunity 
where id in (select OpportunityId
         from OpportunityHistory
        where createddate > 2018-02-27T00:00:00.000Z 
        and createddate < 2018-02-27T19:05:00.000Z)
```

Comment: That works!  Now my only issue is that isn't the only condition I need to search against and I'm getting the error: Semi join sub selects are not allowed with the 'or' operator.  Is there any way I can get around that without making two queries?  The query I am trying to make is: Select id, name  from opportunity where (id IN (select opportunityId from OpportunityHistory where createddate>2018-02-27T00:00:00.000Z and createddate<2018-02-27T19:05:00.000Z)) OR (quote_created__c > 2018-02-27T00:05:00.000Z and quote_created__c < 2018-02-27T00:06:00.000Z)

Comment: @ed54 `Select id, name from opportunity 
where id IN (select opportunityId from OpportunityHistory where (createddate>2018-02-27T00:00:00.000Z and createddate<2018-02-27T19:05:00.000Z) OR 
(opportunity.quote_created__c > 2018-02-27T00:05:00.000Z and opportunity.quote_created__c < 2018-02-27T00:06:00.000Z))` -- put the OR in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use apex, you can do this in two steps:

```
List<OpportunityHistory> histories = [select OpportunityId from OpportunityHistory 
          where createddate > 2018-02-27T00:00:00.000Z 
            and createddate < 2018-02-27T19:05:00.000Z];

Set<Id> theIds = new Set<Id>();
for (OpportunityHistory oh : histories) {
    theIds.add(oh.OpportunityId);
}

List<Opportunity> opptys = [select Id from Opportunity where Id in :theIds];
```

That will give you the opportunities that match the criteria you specified above

Comment: I can't use apex.  I am building a separate API that needs to query our sfdc instance for these opportunities.

Comment: Then it'll be 2 API calls, one for each query. You cannot get all that info in a single SoQL statement.